# SUBSTRING_INDEX and MySQL Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, indexing, substring

I am finding it hard to get a MySQL stored procedure to work when I use the SUBSTRING_INDEX and MID and LOCATE functions. The first Select I have works, the other 2 do not.  Any help in getting this to work would be awesome.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Address`(TBL VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN

SET @table_name = TBL;

SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE kalo.",@table_name,' SET AD1 = REPLACE(AD1,".","  ")') INTO @SQL;
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE kalo.",@table_name,' SET STNO = SUBSTRING_INDEX(AD1, ' ', +1)') INTO @SQL;
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SELECT CONCAT("UPDATE kalo.",@table_name,' SET STNM = MID(AD1, LOCATE(' ', AD1) + 1)') INTO @SQL;
PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Comment: Show a sampling of what you are trying to achieve (before and after strings).

Comment: **BEFORE**  
AD1      |STNO |STNM
8950 BARRONS BLVD  | |
3030 CAUSEWAY APPROACH  | | 
  
**AFTER**  
AD1      |STNO |STNM
8950 BARRONS BLVD  |8950 |BARRONS BLVD
3030 CAUSEWAY APPROACH |3030 |CAUSEWAY APPROACH

Comment: I would find it easier to do this kind of parsing in a 'real' language, not SQL.